# Facebook URL Graph Search - Page Queries

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am looking to generate a list of URLS or FB ID's for a set of existing Facebook Pages. Ultimately the initial query I am looking to run is simple: Find all NEW facebook pages created in City XYZ.

The term NEW, is open to interpretation. It could mean "Created this month" Or newer relative others in a set (these details are not important at the moment) . Also, "Pages" refers to fan pages (not user profiles).

I have identified 3 possible approaches. Both of which I am hoping to get some input on. Regarding feasibility and process.

Option 1) Somehow leverage Facebook's Graph API and develop some time of web application to generate a list of all Pages, then filter by city, then filter by date created.

Option 2 (Best Case)) Write or generate a custom Graph Search URL with embedded search criteria and leverage FBs existing search feature to get results. A great example of this approach is used by the tool searchisback.com. Only this tool is used to do advanced searches on People, but I need advanced searches on Pages.

Option 3) Locate a tool that already does this that I can use.

I again hoping to get some input and possible some direction/recommendations. 
I should also mention that I actually know very little about Facebook APIs and Facebook Development. My position right now is of some who knows what they want to do, but no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Not possible, you can only search for Pages by name, the Graph Search is not available with the API. Those are all the options: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search

Option 2: See answer to option 1.

Option 3: There are tools that list Pages, but they all have to add them manually. So there is not really a tool that does what you want to achieve.

**In short: What you want to do is not possible.**